# CakePHP 3 : creating multidimensional cookie

Tags: cakephp, cookies, multidimensional-array, cakephp-3.2

I'm working in CakePHP 3.2 and building a shopping cart.

I'm using `Cookie` component to store the products in the cart.

This is what I'm doing to add products to the cart

```
public function addToCart()
    {
      $this->loadModel('Products');

      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $p_id = $this->request->data('product_id');
        $p_quantity = $this->request->data('qnty');

        $product = $this->Products->get($p_id);

        if (!$product) {
          throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Product'));
        }

          $this->Cookie->write('Cart',
            ['id' => $p_id, 'quantity' => $p_quantity]);

          $itemsCount = count($this->Cookie->read('Cart'));

          $this->Flash->success(__('Product added to cart'));
          return $this->redirect($this->referer());

      }
    }
```

How could I add multidimensional array in Cookie because Cart can have multiple products and each product carry multiple value.
Also, How could I print in `view` of `cart()` method ?

This is how my `cart()` method is

```
public function cart()
    {
      $cart_products = $this->Cookie->read('Cart');

      $this->set('cart_products', $cart_products);
    }
```

and printing in view as

```
foreach($cart_products as $c_product):
  echo $c_product->id.' : '.$c_product->quantity;   // line 45
endforeach;
```

But this gives error as

```
Trying to get property of non-object [ROOT/plugins/ArgoSystems02/src/Template/Orders/cart.ctp, line 45]
```

Comment: use echo $c_product['id'].' : '.$c_product['quantity']; on line 45

Comment: this is correct to print a single cookie value. What I want to store an array in cookie and loop through it to print all `id` and `quantity`. This code required to remove `foreach()` loop and is printed using `$cart_products['id']`

Comment: Kindly check with my answer and let me know Thanks :-)

Comment: Before check you clear all cookies and caches & test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write array to cookie:

```
$this->Cookie->write('Cart', ['id' => $p_id, 'quantity' => $p_quantity]);
```

I believe what You want is to store all products in cookie:

```
$cart = $this->Cookie->read('Cart') ? $this->Cookie->read('Cart') : [];
$cart[] = $product;
$this->Cookie->write('Cart', $cart)
```

Comment: From your first line, everytime I add a new product, data of previously written item is replaced by new one. I want to add all products without replacing one.

Comment: It reads already added products or creates new array if cookie does not exists.

Comment: How to update a particular array value in this cookie

Comment: @anujsharma9196 You get from the cookie and by using for loop check the id if exists then overwrite the quantity and also take the remaining to temp array finally overwrite the new array to cookie

Comment: @MathsRkBala can you answer it [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348282/cakephp-3-delete-and-update-array-from-cookie) I have created a separate question for this

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

Instead of Method

```
$this->Cookie->write('Cart',['id' => $p_id, 'quantity' => $p_quantity]);
```

Into

```
$cart = [];
if($this->Cookie->check('Cart')){
    $cart = $this->Cookie->read('Cart');
}
$cart[] = ['id' => $p_id, 'quantity' => $p_quantity];//multiple
$this->Cookie->write('Cart', $cart);
```

Instead of View

```
foreach($cart_products as $c_product):
  echo $c_product->id.' : '.$c_product->quantity;   // line 45
endforeach;
```

Into

```
foreach($cart_products as $c_product):
  echo $c_product['id'].' : '.$c_product['quantity'];   // line 45
endforeach;
```